# How to integrate a loop in another loop in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, foreach

For the code below I am trying to include another loop into the foreach statement.
I have two lists. 
The first one "item" is my list where I check the elements if they are zero or not.
The second list "varis" is my list where the values are saved for the case the values are not zero.

I want to check if the values in my list "item" are zero, if so set the elements as zero.
If not set the value of the first element as the first value listed in my list varis.
Same goes for the second element. If the second element is not zero set the value as the second value listed in varis and so on.
So far I used the foreach statement to check my elements of my "item" list.
However I'm not sure how to go about my second list.
I am thinking about integrating a second loop into my foreach statement.
But I don't know how.

```
$sums = (2+4+5+6+5+10+4); 
my @item=(0,50,5,3,5,15,0);
$sum = 0;
my @varis = (2,4,5,6,5,10,4);

foreach my $item(@item){
        if ( $item==0) {$item=0}    # if element in item is zero set element as zero
           else {$item=$varis;}     # else for element in @item set the value as the first element in @varis, for the second element (if it's not zero) in @item add the second element and so on     
       $sum = $sum + $item;         # sum all the values
    }

    $result = $sums/$sum;
    print "$result\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `$varis[$i]` where `$i` is the index of the element of `@items` being processed, but you don't have `$i`. As such, you need to iterate over the indexes of `@items` instead of iterating over its elements.

Solution:

```
my $sum = 0;
for my $i (0..$#items) { 
   my $item;
   if ($items[$i] == 0) {
      $item = 0;
   } else {
      $item = $varis[$i];
   }

   $sum = $sum + $item;
}
```

Simplified solution:

```
my $sum = 0;
for my $i (0..$#items) {
    $sum += $varis[$i] if $items[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the longer solution worked. I just removed the s from items and the code worked perfectly.

Comment: Rather, you should add the `s` to the existing variable. It ends up being less confusing if you use plural for your collections.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll change that